# When using an exe file, it writes QImage:: scaled: Image is a null image when processing jpg

Tags: c++, qt, scale, qimage

When compiling in qt, there is no such problem , but if I do it in an exe file, all formats except jpg work. JPG returns the error " QImage:: scaled: Image is a null image when processing jpg"

code:

```
char type_cpy[4] ;
strcpy(type_cpy, picture.type.toStdString().c_str());

QString path(picture.way+"Resized");
QDir dir;
if(!dir.exists(path))
    dir.mkpath(path);

QString link_to_picture = picture.way + picture.name;
QString link = picture.way+"Resized"+"\\" + picture.full_name;

QRect rect(0, 0, picture.size.width, picture.size.height);
QImage original(link_to_picture);

if(picture.mode == "Crop" || picture.mode == "crop")
{
    QImage cropped = original.copy(rect);
    cropped.save(link, type_cpy, -1);
}
else if(picture.mode == "Exact" || picture.mode == "exact")
{
    QImage scaled = original.scaled(picture.size.width, picture.size.height, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    scaled.save(link, type_cpy, -1);
}
```

Comment: Where's qjpeg.dll in your environment when you run it?

Comment: It should be in the exe folder ?

Comment: On our app, it's in the imageformats subfolder.

Comment: I added this file using this path ImgSizer\plugins\imageformats\ 
not help

Comment: Maybe, have a look at [Deploying Qt Applications](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html). I haven't much experience but used it successfully on Windows to make little helper tools self-standing for my own purposes as well as deploying them to other persons/PCs.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ? If yes, please share the answer.